# unique .htaccess question about mod_rewrite and RewriteCond

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewritecond

I have a few rewrite rules like these

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)-something.html otherdir/file1.php?var1=val&var2=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/ otherdir/file2.php?var1=val [L,NC]
```

dir/ is not a real directory.  Everything above works as expected.

However, the user is able to type anything like

```
mysite.com/dir/asdfasdfasdfsdf
```

And they are still redirected to file2.php.  If the user types in just garbage I'd like to serve a 404 instead.

I'm guessing I need a RewiteCond that will test for blank space after the slash and only then serve file2.php, but I'm unsure how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you put a `$` at the end of `dir/` it will do the trick (note that I haven't tested this, so please try it out before voting me up or anything). The `$` means "end of string" in the same way that `^` means "beginning of string".

```
RewriteRule ^dir/$ otherdir/file2.php?var1=val [L,NC]
```

Good luck!

--jed

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!  I can't vote up yet (reputation) or I would.

Comment: Also made me realize that I needed a $ after the .html in the other rules.  Appreciate it!